# Having Issue on Combining Data Attribute of Parent and Child Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I can add `.active` class to the each link which's parent has a specific data attribute?

I need to add the `.active` class to the `.slide-link` not the parent which holding the data attribute

```js
$('.slide-link[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
$('.slide-link').parent().data('[data-slide="0"]').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" data-slide="0">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">0</a>
</div>

<div class="" data-slide="1">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">1</a>
</div>

<div class="" data-slide="2">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `jQuery('[data-slide="0"]').has(".slide-link").children().addClass('active');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is add the class to the children (with the `slide-link` class) of all elements that have `[data-slide="0"]`, like so:

```js
$('[data-slide="0"]').children('.slide-link').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" data-slide="0">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">0</a>
</div>

<div class="" data-slide="1">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">1</a>
</div>

<div class="" data-slide="2">
<a class="slide-link" href="#">2</a>
</div>
```

Your first snippet didn't work, because there aren't any elements with a class of `slide-link` and `data-slide="0"`. Your second snippet produces an error, because jQuery's `data` method only returns strings or undefined, which both don't have an `addClass()` method.